# Local reduce with specified slices over a single axis in tensorflow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I am trying to perform a local reduce with specified slices over a single axis on a 2D array.

I achieved this using numpy's `numpy.ufunc.reduceat` or `numpy.add.reduceat` but I would like do the same in tensorflow as the input to this reduce operation is an output from tensorflow convolution.

I came across `tf.math.reduce_sum` but I am not sure how this can be used in my case.

It will be great if I can do the `reduceat` operation in tensorflow as I can take advantage of a GPU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do almost the same using [`tf.math.segment_sum`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/segment_sum):

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

def add_reduceat_tf(a, indices, axis=0):
    a = tf.convert_to_tensor(a)
    indices = tf.convert_to_tensor(indices)
    # Transpose if necessary
    transpose = not (isinstance(axis, int) and axis == 0)
    if transpose:
        axis = tf.convert_to_tensor(axis)
        ndims = tf.cast(tf.rank(a), axis.dtype)
        a = tf.transpose(a, tf.concat([[axis], tf.range(axis),
                                       tf.range(axis + 1, ndims)], axis=0))
    # Make segment ids
    r = tf.range(tf.shape(a, out_type=indices.dtype)[0])
    segments = tf.searchsorted(indices, r, side='right')
    # Compute segmented sum and discard first unused segment
    out = tf.math.segment_sum(a, segments)[1:]
    # Transpose back if necessary
    if transpose:
        out = tf.transpose(out, tf.concat([tf.range(1, axis + 1), [0],
                                           tf.range(axis + 1, ndims)], axis=0))
    return out

# Test
np.random.seed(0)
a = np.random.rand(5, 10).astype(np.float32)
indices = [2, 4, 7]
axis = 1
# NumPy computation
out_np = np.add.reduceat(a, indices, axis=axis)
# TF computation
with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
    out = add_reduceat_tf(a, indices, axis=axis)
    out_tf = sess.run(out)
# Check result
print(np.allclose(out_np, out_tf))
# True
```

You can replace [`tf.math.segment_sum`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/segment_sum) above with the reduction function you want to use. The only difference between this and the actual [`np.ufunc.reduceat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html) is the special case where `indices[i] >= indices[i + 1]`. The posted function requires `indices` to be sorted, and if there were a case where `indices[i] == indices[i + 1]` the corresponding `i` position in the output would be zero, not `a[indices[i]]`.